# Big-O notation for cellular automaton algorithm

Tags: algorithm, big-o, notation

#### Problem

I am new to **Big-O** notation, attempting to find the **Big-O** notation for a cellular automaton algorithm.

#### Algorithm

The algorithm I am using is as follows:

```
Ai-1 = Ai;
Row_Rand = Random(1,ny);
Col_Rand = Random(1,nx);
For r = 1:ny
    For c = 1:nx
        IF Col_Rand(c) == 1
            Ai (Row_Rand(r),Col_Rand(c))= Boundary_Rules(bi2dec(Ai-1(Row_Rand(r),Col_Rand(c)), Ai-1(Row_Rand(r),Col_Rand(c)),, Ai-1(Row_Rand(r),Col_Rand(c)+1)));
        ELSEIF Col_Rand(c) == nx
            Ai (Row_Rand(r),Col_Rand(c))= Boundary_Rules(bi2dec(Ai-1(Row_Rand(r),Col_Rand(c)-1), Ai-1(Row_Rand(r),Col_Rand(c)),, Ai-1(Row_Rand(r),Col_Rand(c))));
        ELSE
            Ai (Row_Rand(r),Col_Rand(c))= Rules(bi2dec(Ai-1(Row_Rand(r),Col_Rand(c)-1), Ai-1(Row_Rand(r),Col_Rand(c)), Ai-1(Row_Rand(r),Col_Rand(c)+1)));
        END
    END
END
```

#### Assuming:

- The matrices "Ai", "Boundary_Rules" and "Rules" are already defined in memory.
- The variables "ny" and "nx" are already defined in memory and correspond to the number of pixels in an image in both the **y** and **x** directions respectively.
- The function "Random" is the Modern “Fisher-Yates Shuffle” function with **O(N)**, where **N** is the size of the shuffle space.
- The function "bi2dec" turns the binary values stored in Ai-1 into a decimal value for array referencing.

Would I be correct in saying that the **Big-O** notation for this algorithm is **O(ny * nx) = O(N)** (where N = ny * nx, the total number of pixels in an image).

Also, if this algorithm was then nested inside a `for` loop which runs for a designated number of iterations (**Nit**) would the **Big-O** notation then become **O(Nit*N)** where **Nit** would become the dominant factor if it is greater than N?

Comment: Big O is generally used to compare relative complexities. So O(N) works if your intention is to measure in terms of total number of pixels.

Comment: That is my intention, thank you for your input

Comment: The first part was answered by `ffejrekaburb`, in the second part, if Nit and N are comparable, then `O(N^2)` but if `Nit >> N` or `N>>Nit`, Then the time complexity will be `O(Nit)` or `O(N)`, but these complexities are not calculated using amortized analysis:)

Comment: Thank you very much, you have helped give me confidence in my work.